# Minimum Sdk support doesn't work for my app. How to resolve this?

Tags: android

I've just developed an app. I set API23 while creating project. Now I changed Min Sdk version to API 16 via File>Project Structure > app>flavors. But app won't run other than API 23 (Marshmallows).... What do I do now??

Comment: You are probably using dependencies that are compatabile API23+. I have to find them and try make it compatibile

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the minSdk to 16 in the build.gradle?

Comment: I've found the problem..  `import android.icu.text.DecimalFormat;'` is the reason. But I need text formating in Kitkat too what should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add minSdkVersion to 16 in your app>build.gradle file:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}
```